# How to extract part of big html string that is between two diffrent unique patterns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I got is an HTML string from `XMLHttpRequest` and I posted it to a textbox.

```
document.myform.outputtext.value = xhr.responseText;
```

But I only want part of that big HTML string that is between `</fb:send>` and `<div class="styles">`. I have done similar things in PHP but don't know how I can do that in JavaScript? All I want is the `xhr.responseText` part that is between `</fb:send>` and `<div class="styles">`. I'd be happy if some one help me with this. Thanks.

PHP example:

```
$start = strpos($file_contents, '</fb:send>');
$end = strpos($file_contents, '<div class="styles">', $start);
$code = substr($file_contents, $start, $end);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var start = xhr.responseText.indexOf('</fb:send>');
var end = xhr.responseText.indexOf('<div class="styles">', start);
var code = xhr.responseText.substring(start, end);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regexes are cool.

```
var html = "foo</fb:send>bar<div class=\"styles\">baz";
var code = html.match(/<\/fb\:send>(.*?)<div class="styles">/)[1];
console.log(code); // 'bar'
```

Just don't expect them to do the [job of an HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: @Jeff I edited that very link in there before you commented it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `indexOf` and `substring`? Here is an example:

```
<script>
var stringTxt = "123abcxyz890";
var start = stringTxt.indexOf("a");
var end = stringTxt.indexOf("z", start);
var newStringTxt = stringTxt.substring(start, end);
</script>
```